# Redirect en nginx a https

Tags: nginx

buenas noches, no se por que no me redirecciona al https: Cuando pongo el .es o el .com sin el https:// me sale la pagina de nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com dominio.es www.dominio.es
    return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
    
}
    server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

        server_name dominio.com; # Aquí va sin www


    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/pizzaConstruccion/;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, te falta un punto y coma al final de la línea `server_name`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com dominio.es www.dominio.es
    return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
}
```

Eso provoca que lo que hay en la siguiente línea (`return`, `301` y `https://dominio.com$request_uri`) se interprete como más parámetros (nombres de dominios) de `server_name`.

Lo correcto sería:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com dominio.es www.dominio.es;
    return 301 https://dominio.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: jajja que torpeza la mia, gracias @OscarGarcia